# Sending php variables within an echo'd form

Tags: php, mysql

Got myself into a *bit of a pickle* attempting to send over a **custom variable** to paypal when the button is clicked

I'm currently *adamant* that this is the problem I'm having and why the transactions **aren't executing correctly**

**So here's my code:**

```
<?php
                $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT is_member FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
                $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
                $isMember = $row['is_member'];
                if ($isMember == 0){
                echo'
                <p>To gain access to the members section and receive daily horse racing tips from our professionals purchase premium membership</a></p>
                <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id;">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CVWJZN5AALBVJ">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
                ';

                }else{
                echo'<p> You are a member, <a href="membership.php">click here</a> to access the membership page </p>';
                }
                ?>
```

**The problem I'm having is this line:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id;">
```

Sending the ID of the user to paypal. I know how to do this normally, but because I'm already echoing out the form I don't believe I need to use new php tags to echo out the variable

*I have tried many different ways of passing it, just want to get the correct one!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick solution:

Write that line like this:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $id . '">'
```

Entire code:

```
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT is_member FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
                $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
                $isMember = $row['is_member'];
                if ($isMember == 0){
                echo'
                <p>To gain access to the members section and receive daily horse racing tips from our professionals purchase premium membership</a></p>
                <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $id . '">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CVWJZN5AALBVJ">
                <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
                ';

                }else{
                echo'<p> You are a member, <a href="membership.php">click here</a> to access the membership page </p>';
                }
```

What I would have done if I were you:

```
<?php
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT is_member FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
                    $row = $check->fetch_assoc();
                    $isMember = $row['is_member'];
                    if ($isMember == 0){
                    ?>
                    <p>To gain access to the members section and receive daily horse racing tips from our professionals purchase premium membership</a></p>
                    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CVWJZN5AALBVJ">
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form>
                    <?php

                    }else{
                    echo'<p> You are a member, <a href="membership.php">click here</a> to access the membership page </p>';
                    }
?>
```

Comment: To add, this is because variables aren't interpolated when using single quotes for the string, only double quotes.

Comment: Thank you, turns out the problem wasn't even the id :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this (among other) :

- Classic concatenation :

  ```
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $id . '">';
  ```
- Use of [double quotes wrapping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) :

  ```
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='custom' value='$id'>";
  ```
- Use of [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :

  ```
  echo <<<EOF
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$id">
  EOF;
  ```

If you use Heredoc, don't forget to place the ending label without any preceding space, on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you're using *single* quots, which just echo (->value="$id;"), instead of *double* quots, in which PHP searchs for variables and inserts them: (->value="1").

So you could use double quots: (than you need to escape the HTML double quots)

`echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"custom\" value=\"$id;\">";`

Or just concat this into your String: (with the point (concatenation) operator)

`echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$id.'">';`

Hope I could help, *-Minding*